# Do Azure Mobile Apps use Azure AD B2C for authentication?

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-mobile-services, azure-ad-b2c

My question is pretty simple and straight forward.

**Azure Mobile Apps** claim they provide authentication with azure active directory, facebook and other social networks, my question is, are they actually using **Azure AD B2C** behind the scenes? because the features seem to be almost the same.

Comment: I don't think they do because this type of authentication was available in Mobile Apps before Azure AD B2C became available. B2C went GA just last year (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azuread-b2c-ga-announcement/)

Comment: and b2c is actually better than the authentication provided by the azure mobile apps, because b2c also provides password reset and a few extra services, right?

Comment: These  Identity authentication are all based on Azure AD, including Azure AD B2C itself. Azure AD B2C is just a service under Azure AD.

Comment: @WayneYang-MSFT where are the user information and claims are stored for azure mobile authentication?

Comment: @batmaci User information is stored in AAD and also a service principal in that tenant.

Comment: @WayneYang-MSFT i am using .net backend but i cant seem to have any access to it. is it not visible to us? i can retrieve logins using code

Comment: @batmaci This shouldn’t discuss this question here. If you have any questions,you can post it and specify more details about your scenario.